# How can I print just a unix newline in Perl on Win32?

Tags: perl, newline

By default, perl prints \r\n in a win32 environment. How can I override this? I'm using perl to make some changes to some source code in a repository, and I don't want to change all the newline characters.

I tried changing the output record separator but with no luck.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Wanted to include a code sample - I'm doing a search and replace over some files that follow a relatively straightforward pattern like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# test.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
$\ = "\n"; 
$^I=".old~";

while (<>) {
  while (s/hello/world/) {

  }
  print;
}
```

This should replace any instances of "hello" with "world" for any files passed on the cmd line.

**Edit 2:** I tried the `binmode` as suggested without any luck *initially*. I delved a bit more and found that `$^I` (the inplace edit special variable) was overriding `binmode`. Any work around to still be able to use the inplace edit?

**Edit 3:** As Sinan points out below, I needed to use `binmode ARGVOUT` with `$^I` instead of `binmode STDOUT` in my example. Thanks.

Comment: If you changed the output record separator, then that was the only thing you can do. I'd guess you made some other mistake (like not actually splitting the incoming lines correctly, or not chomping them).

Comment: Can you give an example of some code that prints `\r\n` when you don't want it?

Comment: @Sinan, why would you assume that I'm unwilling?? I'm not unwilling. I don't have a short script handy. I have a very long, complicated script that probably won't make a lot of sense and would be even more confusing. I can make an abbreviated version later tonight. I thought that I was including the relevant parts. I didn't know the in place edit was relevant at the time. Thx.

Comment: I assumed you were unwilling because I cannot confidently figure out a short test script based on the information you provided. Showing the shebang line is the least you can do to help people who are trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Keith, for accepting my answer. I would like to point out that **`while ( s/hello/world/g )`** is probably what you want rather than `while ( s/hello/world/ )`.

Comment: @Sinan, I believe the g modifier is unnecessary since it's in the while loop - at least, it currently globally replaces without it. However, it raises an interesting question: would it be faster? I think probably so, since it wouldn't have to recompile the regex for each loop and the actual regex that I use has an eval. I'll test. Thx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Printing `"\n"` to a filehandle on Windows emits, by default, a `CARRIAGE RETURN` (`"\015"`) followed by a `LINE FEED` (`"\012"`) character because that the standard newline sequence on Windows.

This happens transparently, so you need to override it for the special filehandle `ARGVOUT` (see [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGVOUT)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak

use strict; use warnings;

local ($\, $/);

while (<>) {
    binmode ARGVOUT;
    print;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> xxd test.txt
0000000: 7465 7374 0d0a 0d0a                      test....

C:\Temp> h test.txt

C:\Temp> xxd test.txt
0000000: 7465 7374 0a0a                           test..
```

See also [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html), [perldoc binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) and [perldoc perliol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perliol.html) (thanks [daotoad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59135/daotoad)).

Comment: It's not really the \n doing anything. It's the filehandle translating \012. That is, without writing to a text filehandle, a \n is still just \012.

Comment: @brian d foy: Clarification added.

Comment: For detailed discussion of Perl IO layers, the mechanism that does this translation, see perldoc perliol - http://perldoc.perl.org/perliol.html

Comment: +1 Thx, it partially worked. Initially, I couldn't get binmode to do what you described. Then I traced it down to $^I. See my edit.  Any work around.

Comment: binmode ARGVOUT did the trick with the inplace edit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Does `binmode( STDOUT )` work?

Comment: Can you flesh out this answer and add some more details?  It's the correct one but explaining more would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your question about the binmode being lost when `$^I` opens a new output handle, you could solve this with the [open](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?open) pragma:

```
use open OUT => ':raw';
```

which will force all filehandles opened for writing to have the ':raw' PerlIO layer (equivalent to `binmode` with no argument) to apply to them. Just take care if you're opening anything *else* for output that you apply `:crlf` or any other layer as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are reading in contains line endings, so you're getting them back out again. You can strip them off yourself with [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), then add your own ending back, provided you have set binmode as Sinan describes::

```
while (<>) {
    binmode;
    chomp;        # strip off \r\n
    while (s/search/replace/) {
        # ...
    }
    print;
    print "\n";   # add your own line ending back
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, perl prints \r\n in a win32 environment. How can I override this?

I ended up creating my own file and setting `binmode(fh)` specifically.  I could not get `STDOUT` (or `ARGVOUT`) to work reliably under both Windows 10 using perl 5.8.8 and Windows 7 with perl 5.14.4.

```
perl -e 'open(fh, ">x"); binmode(fh); print fh "\n";' ; od -c x
0000000  \n
```

Sometimes the `binmode(fh)` was needed here and sometimes it seemed to be the default.

I could not get `binmode(STDOUT)` to be work reliably.  Some of the following did output just `\n` under Windows:

```
perl -e 'binmode(ARGVOUT); print "\n";' | od -c
perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT); print "\n";' | od -c
perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT); syswrite(STDOUT, "\n");' | od -c
```

... but then not when the output was going to a file.  The following still spat out `\r \n`.

```
perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT); print "\n";' > x ; od -c x
perl -e 'binmode(ARGVOUT); print "\n";' > x ; od -c x
```

Interestingly, the following worked when piping to `cat` which then writes to a file.  Perl must be seeing if STDOUT is a terminal, file, or pipe and enabling the cr-lf layer or not.  Why a pipe is binary but a file is not is an interesting decision.  There are also differences between running perl interactively from the command-line and running it from a script with the same args and redirects.

```
perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT); print "\n";' | cat > x ; od -c x
```

Noticed that I tried `print` and `syswrite`.  I was surprised that `syswrite` didn't give me a direct layer to the file-handle.  I also tried to copy the `STDOUT` file-handle and set `binmode` on that new file-handle but that didn't work either.  `PERLIO` environmental variable didn't help either.  The `use out => ":raw";` worked under Windows 10 perl 5.8.8 but not Windows 7 perl 5.14.4 when redirected to an output file.

Btw, I wasn't doing a `print "\n";` in my code when I stumbled over this problem.  I was doing a `print` of `pack("c", $num);` where `$num` happened to be 10.  Imagine my surprise when my binary file was corrupted by `\r`s.

Porting sucks!

Answer (score -1):

A unix newline is a LINEFEED character, which is ASCII code 10.

`print "\012";`

Comment: On Windows: `perl -e "print qq{\012}" | xxd` yields `0000000: 0d0a` unless you set `binmode STDOUT`.

Comment: It's not a problem with getting the right character. It's the text-mode translation that's modifying the output while writing to a text filehandle.

Comment: thanks for correcting me on Windows; I'd forgotten that perl "helped" even when explicitly told what to do.